# Swift WKWebView continuous spell checking

Tags: swift, macos, webview, wkwebview

We have an embedded HTML form type editor in a macOS app that needs to be filled by the user. We are using WKWebView with Swift and it's all working fine but we are not able to get the spell check working in WKWebView. I mean it does work and corrects some words but doesn't show red dotted underline on misspelled words like WebView.

WebView shows dotted redline where WKWebView does not. Found that WebView has property as `isContinuousSpellCheckingEnabled` but no such property is available in WKWebView.

My simple requirement to highlight misspelled words, please help if there's anything available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not found it yet: so far no such property is available in WKWebView.

*[From apple](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188800)*

**Description Daniel Bates 2018-08-21 11:23:20 PDT**

> We should render misspelled words with the spelling correction dots in
>   iOS WebKit (i.e. when using WKWebView). Currently we only support this
>   in iOS WebKit Legacy (i.e. when using UIWebView).

Comment: That's not good news, maybe in newer SDK's they will add. Thanks.

Comment: @MP did you ever figure this out or find a suitable workaround?

Comment: @NSExceptional, not really, I am living with this limitation until Apple adds this feature or something else comes in.